# The difference between KP+Inf+Pow and Z

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, proof-theory

I'd like to clarify some details about the theories Z (= *Zermelo set theory*) and KP+=KP+Infinity+Powerset (KP is *Kripke-Platek set theory*).

In [this paper](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/slim.pdf) (M1), Mathias claims that Z+KP is consistent relative to Z; in particular, this implies that KP+ does not prove Con(Z). Moreover, by explicitly working in Z+KP, Mathias implies that Z does not contain KP. For the former fact he refers to [this other paper](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/maclane.pdf) (M2); however, I can't find that fact in (M2). But I could be missing something obvious - there are a *ton* of subtheories of ZFC discussed in (M2), and the claim could easily be a trivial consequence of one of the theorems Mathias proves, even if it's not stated explicitly.

I'd like to first double-check these claims:

> **Question 1**: Is it true that Z+KP is consistent relative to Z, and that Z does not contain KP? (If the answer to the first point is "yes", is this proved in (M2)? If not, where?)

And then ask a couple related questions, comparing the strengths of Z and KP.

First proof-theoretically:

> **Question 2**: Does Z prove Con(KP+)?

And then set-theoretically:

> **Question 3**: Is the smallest height of a transitive model of KP+ strictly smaller than the smallest height of a transitive model of Z?

I suspect the answers to all three questions are "yes": that is, Z is not stronger than KP+, but it is "morally" stronger. However, I would like to check this.

Comment: For the second part of your Question 1, KP + Inf proves the existence of all computable (von Neumann) ordinals whereas Z doesn't prove that $\omega + \omega$ exists. Thus, it can't be that KP is contained in Z. This also answers your Question 3: $V_{\omega + \omega}$ is a model of Z but any transitive model of KP+ must have height much greater than $\omega + \omega$.

Comment: Kameryn, I'd suggest that you post your comment as an answer, rather than as a comment.

Comment: @KamerynWilliams Oh wow, I knew that but for some reason completely forgot them when I was writing this question. Thanks! I'm still interested in the first part of (1) and in (2), though.

Comment: The first part of Question 1 has a positive answer. Mathias mentioned it in his paper "Slim Models of Zermelo Set Theory," and it follows from Theorem 5 of (M2). (Consistency of $\mathsf{KLZ}$ from that of $\mathsf{Z}$.)

Answer (score 4):

Questions 2 and 3 both have a negative answer.

For 3, $V_{\omega + \omega}$ is a model of Z but KP + Inf proves the existence of all computable ordinals, so the height of a transitive model of KP+ must be much taller than $\omega + \omega$.

For 2, we in fact have that KP+ proves the consistency of Z. This is because from Powerset, $\Sigma_1$-Replacement, and the existence of $V_\omega$ we can prove the existence of $V_{\omega + \omega}$.

Comment: I'm being a bit slow - how is $\Sigma_1$-Replacement enough to get $V_{\omega+\omega}$? The immediate way I see - defining a map sending $n$ to $V_{\omega+n}$ - seems to require $\Sigma_2$-Replacement. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think I was too hasty in saying that. I wanted to construct $V_{\omega + \omega}$ by recursion, using that KP has a version of the recursion theorem. But $x = \mathcal P(y)$ is a $\Pi_1$ property and checking Barwise's book, I'd misremembered the result. It's $\Delta_1$ functions KP can do the recursion theorem for, not $\Pi_1$ functions.

Comment: I don't know much about KP but isn't its scheme of axioms of replacement for $\Sigma_0$ formulas anyway ?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Looking at (M2), in section 6 Mathias shows that the theory he calls $\mathsf{KP}^\mathcal{P}$ proves the existence of $V_{\omega + \omega}$ (page 53). Roughly, $\mathsf{KP}^\mathcal{P}$ is KP but allowing a predicate for the powerset operation in the formulae for Separation/Collection. Also, his Remark 6.29 on the same page gives a transitive model of KP+ which has $V_{\omega + \omega}$ as a subclass but not as a set.

Comment: @Max Yes but you get a little extra Replacement: it turns out that $\Sigma_1$-Replacement holds. This is nontrivial - see Theorem 4.6 in [chapter I of Barwise's book](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pl/1235418473).

Comment: @KamerynWilliams Does that address my questions? I don't immediately see the connection . . .

Comment: It doesn't directly address your questions, but it seemed like it could be relevant. I don't know your motivation for looking at KP+ in particular, but it could be that $\mathsf{KP}^\mathcal{P}$ is also worth looking at for your purposes.

Comment: @KamerynWilliams My motivation comes from forcing, basically. There's a particular forcing notion I'm interested in - an iteration of forcings which are variations of Hechler forcing - and KP+ is the smallest theory over which it "works properly". (To motivate this, note that in KP+Inf the bare Hechler forcing is a *class* forcing, but adding "$\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ exists" makes it a set forcing.) So I'm interested in understanding where KP+ sits with respect to other weak fragments of ZFC.